# Dictionary attack on wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, dictionary, ip

Someone is permanently trying to hack wordpress website, can someone suggest possible ways to prevent this.

I dont think they will hack it because i have taking all security measures and preventions really strong password etc, its just annoying i have a plugin call activity monitor which will output below.

[image]

so this just happens then i have to go in and block the ip in my .htaccess file. 115.87.105.135

Heres the info i get from a lookup

IP  :   115.87.105.135       Neighborhood
Host    :   ppp-115-87-105-135.revip4.asianet.co.th
Country :   Thailand

What information can i get from a ip to see who is trying to hack me and where or is there no information i can get just have to keep waiting and blocking ips all the time???

Thanks

Comment: for better security always have a good password which contain at least special character and digit....

Comment: And Regarding this ip you can trace from many website which give you atleast from which country the attack is done and I think the attacker is amertuer as he didn't know all technique to hack any website so don't worry about that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To stop *brute force* attacks by limiting the amount of times people can unsuccessfully login to your Wordpress admin panel, use the [Login LockDown](http://www.bad-neighborhood.com/login-lockdown.html) plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the whois information to learn who is administrating the IP range the IP originates from. They have to provide contact information (email address, ...) to report abuse by their users.

If you are just interested in the location there are ip geolocating services available on the net but they are not very accurate (maybe they'll show the right town).

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code to bottom of your functions.php in theme folder it will stop the ping back request.

```
add_filter( 'xmlrpc_methods', 'remove_xmlrpc_pingback_ping' );
function remove_xmlrpc_pingback_ping( $methods ) {
unset( $methods['pingback.ping'] );

return $methods;
}
```